# Transferring react client-side google sign-in to ASP.NET server-side

Tags: asp.net, reactjs, oauth-2.0, asp.net-identity, google-signin

I am using `react-google-login` library to let users sign in my application on the client-side through Google, which works fine and returns token and profile information.

```
  <GoogleLogin
      clientId="XXXX.apps.googleusercontent.com"
      buttonText="Login"
      onSuccess={responseGoogle}
      onFailure={responseGoogle}
      cookiePolicy={'single_host_origin'}
  />

 const responseGoogle = (response) => {
     console.log(response);
 }
```

Below is the configuration on the server to enable Google Authentication:

```
services.AddAuthentication()
    .AddGoogle(options =>
    {
        IConfigurationSection googleAuthNSection = 
            Configuration.GetSection("Authentication:Google");

        options.ClientId = googleAuthNSection["ClientId"];
        options.ClientSecret = googleAuthNSection["ClientSecret"];
    });
```

But, I do not how to transfer this successful login to the asp.net server-side. How can I use the token sent by google to sign in the user on the server side? I would like to do this for two cases: (a) the email in the system does not match the gmail, (b) the email in the system matches the gmail. I appreciate any help.

Comment: what kind of authentication mechanism are you using on the server side? Usually, the authentication would happen on the server side, which would get a JWT token from your authenticator, and return it to the front-end.

Comment: @GlennvanAcker thanks for the comment. Actually, I did it. But, then what do I do with it from the front end? Do I send it to the server with each request? I am not clear about it.

Comment: Yes, as far as i know, you need to include it in your request, since you'll be protecting your controller actions with it, it needs to be able to authenticate your client. It's really the client that authenticates with google, but it needs to do so in order to protect your API. otherwise, anyone could just talk to the API directly.

Answer (score 7):

Small misunderstanding of the auth process. You can do it in a two ways:

- [client side OAuth](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2UserAgent) (react-google-login)
- [server side OAuth](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer) (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Google)

But you're trying to mix them in one, it's possible but not very useful, because it's harder to handle token expiration and also scopes for client side are limited in security reasons.

You need to go with next instructions to implement server side OAuth, and you don't need to use `react-google-login`:

1. [Facebook, Google, and external provider authentication in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio)
2. [Google external login setup in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/google-logins?view=aspnetcore-3.0)

Comment: If it is going to help anyone (as I spent some time troubleshooting), I have documented the server-side flow using Asp.NET Identity here  https://mahdikarimipour.com/blog/google-auth-for-react-with-aspnet-identity.